# Reduce space between footnote and page number

Tags: formatting

I am fairly new to LaTeX so please bear with me. I am trying to reduce the space between the footnote and the page numbering (see screenshots in the attachment). What command will do the trick?

Cheers,
JAy
[image: Sample 1]
[image: Sample 2]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ensure that you have no `\raggedbottom` somewhere in your document. Then you can adjust `footskip` using `geometry` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[margin=1in,footskip=0.1in]{geometry}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\begin{document}
  \kant[1-3]\footnote{some}
  \kant[1-24]
\end{document}
```

Adjust the `footskip` value as you desire.

[image]

A better setting may include

```
\usepackage[margin=1in,includehead,includefoot,headheight=0.5in,headsep=0.2in,footskip=0.2in,heightrounded]{geometry}
```

with suitable values.